# Get email text from TextArea on Gmail

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to develop a extension to Chrome which interact with Gmail, more precisely with textarea of an email.
I already check all divs with firebug, but I cannot find the div where the text is.

How can I find the textarea, it has a fix id?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail mail composer area is not a textarea. It is a webpage with contenteditable attribute. Also it is included within an iframe. Id of this iframe is canvas_frame.

This iframe includes another iframe and this is the one containing editable area.

There isn't an easy way to inject to this. This is an option that I've thought quickly:

- In canvas iframe, src is some url (something like that: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&view=bsp&ver=ohhl4rw8mb8y) You can prepare a script to work only in this page. Then you can access to the very first iframe to access the editable content.

Comment: Hi, if I look for element body with class="editable.LW-avf" I can found the Gmail mail composer area. Thanks ;)

Comment: If my answer is helpful, you can vote it and/or accept as answer.